# paragraph indentation inside an indented environment

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, thmtools

I have used the thmtools-package to create a new proof environment. With the following code I indented the whole environment:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{prf}{
  \patchcmd\@thm{\trivlist}{\list{}{\leftmargin25pt}}{}{}
  \patchcmd\thmt@original@endprf{\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}
}
```

The problem is now that when I have multiple paragraphs inside this environment, the paragraph indentation is not visible anymore (`\setlength{\parindent}{25pt}`). How could I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

---

This should demonstrate the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=\topsep,
    spacebelow=\topsep,
    headformat={\NAME},
    headfont=\bfseries,
    notefont=\normalfont,
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    headindent=0pt,
    headpunct={\ },
    qed =\qedsymbol
]{proof}
\declaretheorem[style=proof,name=Proof,numbered=no]{prf}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{prf}{%
  \patchcmd\@thm{\trivlist}{\list{}{\leftmargin25pt}}{}{}
  \patchcmd\thmt@original@endprf{\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}
}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{25pt}


\begin{document}
\section{Section}
Some text\\
And more text

Here the paragraph is indented.

\begin{prf}
Some text\\
And more text

Here the paragraph is not (visibly) indented.
\end{prf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please provide a complete small document that shows the problem. Do you mean that if you don't have those lines there is indentation? An example that we could run would make it a lot clearer.

Comment: Possibly you want to set `\listparindent` instead but without any supplied example that is only a wild guess.

Comment: I hope this example makes my problem clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reinstate the paragraph indentation, by setting the `\listparindent` parameter:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=\topsep,
    spacebelow=\topsep,
    headformat={\NAME},
    headfont=\bfseries,
    notefont=\normalfont,
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    headindent=0pt,
    headpunct={\ },
    qed =\qedsymbol
]{proof}
\declaretheorem[style=proof,name=Proof,numbered=no]{prf}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{prf}{%
  \patchcmd\@thm{\trivlist}{\list{}{\leftmargin25pt\listparindent\parindent}}{}{}
  \patchcmd\thmt@original@endprf{\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}
}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{25pt}


\begin{document}
\section{Section}
Some text\\
And more text

Here the paragraph is indented.

\begin{prf}
Some text\\
And more text

Here the paragraph is indented.
\end{prf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The `ntheorem` package is compatible with `thmtools` and already defines a `\theoremindent`. In the following example from an old file of mine, I had set `\theoremindent{1cm}` and, as you can see, inside the proof environment,  paragraph indent is preserved:

[image]